# Demonstrate that a function is periodic knowing symmetry axis.

Tags: functions

Let

$$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

with symmetry axis at $x = {1,2}$.

Demonstrate that the function is periodic.

Comment: Draw any function definited on $[1,2]$ and then try to continue it, so that it satisfies the above symmetry requirements... the proof is nothing but the formalization of the drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for all $x\in \mathbb R$
$$f(1+x)=f(1-x)$$
and
$$f(2+x)=f(2-x)$$
by assumption.

So that gives us
$$f(2+x) = f(2-x) = f(1-(-1+x)) = f(1+(-1+x)) = f(x). $$
So we have shown periodicity with period $2$.